# Solve difference equation

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Fix a real number $a\not=0$. How to solve recursive equation $a_{n+1}+(2-na)a_n+a_{n-1}=0$. Even a solution for a prescribed value of $a$ should be fine.

Comment: I do not think you can have a closed form solution.

Comment: What about $a_0$ and $a_1$ ? Are they given ?

Comment: If this is a homework, problem, I'd be very interested in your class's subject matter.  The general solution involves Bessel functions.

Comment: I know my $a_0=0$ but $a_1$ can be any real number perhaps nonzero.@Mhenni .i agree with you, but still hopeful

Comment: @eric.no its not.actually came up while i was trying to describe eigenfunctions of certain operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$a_n = c_1 J_{n-\frac{2}{a}}\left(\frac{2}{a}\right) + c_2 Y_{n-\frac{2}{a}}\left(\frac{2}{a}\right)$ for arbitrary constants $c_1, c_2$.

With the initial conditions $a_0 = 0, a_1=a_1$, this becomes
$$a_n = \frac{\pi  a_1}{a} \left(Y_{-\frac{2}{a}}\left(\frac{2}{a}\right)
   J_{n-\frac{2}{a}}\left(\frac{2}{a}\right)-J_{-\frac{2}{a}}\left(\frac{2}
   {a}\right) Y_{n-\frac{2}{a}}\left(\frac{2}{a}\right)\right)$$

Verified with Mathematica${}^{[1]}$.

[1] Wolfram Research, Inc., Mathematica, Version 9.0, Champaign, IL (2012).

Comment: So i assume  J and Y are Bessel functions of first and second type?

Comment: @BigM: Yes, those are they.

Comment: Then knowing in my case $a_n\rightarrow 0$ Then $a_n=0$ For all n.hoping thats something interesting.

Comment: (+1) This follows from the well known relation for the Bessel function of the first kind $ J_{\nu+1}(z)=\frac{2\nu}{z} J_{\nu}(z) - J_{\nu-1} $ and same for the other solution.